# How to specify default Logback configuration for any spring profile that is not already present in the config

Tags: spring, logback, spring-logback

Here is my simplified logback-spring.xml configuration:

```xml
<configuration>

    <!-- appender config -->

    <springProfile name=dev>
        <!-- dev specific config here -->
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name=prod>
        <!-- prod specific config here -->
    </springProfile>

    <!-- other profiles -->

</configuration>
```

I would like to get some default logback configuration when I am running my app with some different profile. I couldn't find information about having some default configuration in `logback-spring.xml`.

Please, note that there are more than 2 profiles defined and I don't know the names of other temp profiles.

Thanks,
Pavlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, found out that defining configuration outside of the profile tag does the job:

```
<configuration>

    <!-- appenders and profiles -->

    <root level="level here">
        <appender-ref ref="name here"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="name here" level="level here"/>
    <!-- other loggers -->

</configuration>
```

In this case it will be taken as a base configuration. You can override appender-ref and loggers in profile specific block.

Answer (score 9):

You can define it like this:

```
<configuration>

<!-- appender config -->

<springProfile name=dev>
    <!-- dev specific config here -->
</springProfile>

<springProfile name=prod>
    <!-- prod specific config here -->
</springProfile>

<!-- other profiles -->

<springProfile name="!(dev| prod)">
   <!-- other specific config here -->
</springProfile>
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but I was wondering whether there is any solution that won't make me list all the profiles in the default config.

Comment: In the asnwers sample you need to define only specific configuration which differs
For other you can list them by  name=!(dev| prod) .. 
If you want genral for some you can use name=(dev| prod)

Comment: this is true ONLY if the springprofiles are specified after the 'default' Logback configuration, otherwise is always taken the default config